# Image name with '%' in it not rendering in browser

Tags: html

I am referencing image with the name - 'a%1.jpg'. It is not rendering in the browser. My image tag looks like `<img src="a%1.jpg" id="Image1" />` Is there anything I can do to use escape sequence - to render the image properly.

Comment: Is there no file extension? It won't know which mime type

Comment: Can you not rename the image file?

Comment: Edited - included the file extension.

Comment: Remember [URL encoding](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm)... `%` == `%25`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percent signs in URLs should be [encoded](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm) as `%25`:

```
<img src="a%251.jpg" id="Image1" />
```